# Spring Boot/JUnit - No qualifying bean of type 'boolean' available

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have been using Spring for a number of months now, but still do not understand some of the various subtleties imposed by the framework.

I am trying to execute a unit test for a class and am running into the often seen error message and exception:

```
***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Parameter 1 of constructor in <package>.MessagingManager required a bean of type 'boolean' that could not be found.

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'boolean' in your configuration.

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'boolean' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.
```

The unit test class (`messagingManager` is the SUT):

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {MessagingManager.class})
public class TestMessagingManager {

  @Autowired
  private MessagingManager messagingManager;
  ...
```

A configuration class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableScheduling
@EnableAsync
@ComponentScan({"<package 1>"})
public class ServiceConfigurer {
  ...
  @Value("${service.name}")
  private String         serviceName;
  ...
  @Bean(name = "messagingManager")
  public MessagingManager messagingManager() {
    return new MessagingManager(serviceConfig(), "MISSION_PLANNER".equals(serviceName));
  }
  ...
  @Bean
  public ServiceConfig serviceConfig() {
    return config.getServiceByName(serviceName);
  }
  ...
}
```

The SUT class:

```
public class MessagingManager {
  ...
  public MessagingManager(ServiceConfig serviceCfg, boolean transactional) {
    ...
  }
  ...
}
```

I tried using `org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils.setField()` to set the `serviceName` field in the `ServiceConfigurer` class, but that did not help. I suspect it doesn't work because the problem is occurring when DI is involved and that the reflection utility usage is "too late". Just a guess.

What am I doing wrong?

If I were to entertain the idea of "creating a bean of type boolean", how do I define a bean that simply holds a boolean value, that's set based on the value of another configured piece of information? Are there alternatives?

Comment: Seems the code you shows is not the root cause of the problem. Try inspect more.

Answer (score 2):

With

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { MessagingManager.class })
```

Spring tries to add a bean of type `MessagingManager` to your context. It does so by invoking the only available constructor. Spring now want to inject beans of type `ServiceConfig` and `boolean` as constructor parameters. But this fails because there is no bean of type `boolean` in the test context.

One solution would be to change this line to

```
@SpringBootTest(classes = { ServiceConfigurer.class })
```

because `ServiceConfigurer` knows how to construct a bean of type `MessagingManager`.

To inject properties to your test you can add

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = { "service.name=example" })
```

to your test class.